Error when building Amazon Chime SDK JS: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
When building the Amazon Chime SDK JS cloned from git, I encountered the following error: "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command".
Things I've tried:
Executed 'npm install -g typescript'
Changed the target path in 'generate-red-worker-code.js' (runCommandWithLogs('./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build config/tsconfig.red.json');) to an absolute path starting from the C drive.
Neither of these attempts led to a resolution.
If anyone knows a solution, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
git/amazon-chime-sdk-js (main)
$ npm run build

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 prebuild
> ruby script/conditional-install

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 615 packages, and audited 616 packages in 13s

54 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Running npm ci to regenerate node_modules.
--> npm ci

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 build
> node script/barrelize.js && node script/generate-version.js && npm run red && npm run tsc:src && npm run tsc:guides && npm run copy

Build description: {
  "hash": "4a9dd14",
  "raw": "v3.22.0",
  "semverString": "3.22.0"
}

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 red
> node script/generate-red-worker-code.js


> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 prebuild
> ruby script/conditional-install

node_modules is up to date.

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Command failed: ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build config/tsconfig.red.json
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

